# Reverse 4017 function

Tags: integrated-circuit

First of all sorry for being noob in circuit.
Here's my problem, I want to have a circuit that will check all lines if it is on or off state. I want to use the same logic of 4017. Rather than providing current to the load in receive current from the line so that I can check if a certain load in open or close.

Here is a typical use of 4017
[image]

But I want it to receive rather than to send, here is my a picture I want to do (sorry for the poor editing of the picture, I don't have any circuit simulator in the computer I use)
[image]
The I1, I2 and I3 are the pins that receive the current if the load is open then the O pin will be the output pin.
So my question is is there an IC with this kind of function or behavior. Thank you.

[Edit]
Sorry for the poor explanation, circuits is not my forte.
The IC will act like the 4017 IC but rather than giving output from the IC it get input from the line or load to know if the line or load is being used or it is in on state. And the output pin will simply be the pin that gives that output, it will gives a on/off state output.

Comment: Your second circuit (as drawn) will simply short out the battery through the leds.

Comment: @JImDearden Sorry for that, I just want to show the idea of what I want to attain, I will edit the 2nd picture if you are being annoyed by it

Comment: IN the question editor, notice the little schematic icon at the top. You can create schematics using that.

Comment: Get rid of the daft schematics and explain what you want. We normally ask for schematics but clearly this is an exception.

Comment: I don't understand the question ?

Comment: @Trevor_G Sorry didn't know that, BTW thanks for the info tho

Comment: Well my question is is there an IC that will act as the 4017 that shifts pin every time it is tap, rather than giving output in get inputs @Trevor_G

Comment: Slow down a bit, and try rewriting the question so a 5 year old will understand it. Right now it's more in your head than in the question. "I1, I2 and I3 are the pins that receive the current if the load is open" ....... "crickets"

Comment: @Francis Gabriel Rodriguez: note that all inputs I1, I2, I3, ... of the IC are shorted to GND. It's really not obvious at all what you want to  accomplish.

Comment: Normally V+ then LED with Rs per LED to detect current with pull down for floating input , then a parallel to serial register may do what you want. This with 9V -3V (LED)=6V ="1" and open LED =0V="0"

Comment: Would a [Priority Encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_encoder) do the job you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Normally V+ then LED with Rs per LED to detect current (with pull down actiing as Curent shunt) and protecting floating input

Buff is part of  parallel input register which  may do what you want.

Output can be serial like Johnson counter. Switch can be on either side.
Register needs Latch input and N clock pulses so this is a sampled input. (not shown)

This with 9V -3V (LED)=6V ="1" and open LED =0V="0"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyynSL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no common IC that combines a counter with a multiplexer. You can use two chips, one as a counter (eg [MC14516B](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC14516B-D.PDF)) and one as a multiplexer (eg [CD4051](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf)).

That seems to describe the function you want, however without some way of knowing which channel is which, it probably won't be very useful.